# how to install ssh in ubuntu 11.10? getting errors while installing ssh anyone please help me

Tags: 11.10

i've run this bellow command

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

getting bellow errors

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package openssh-server is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
```

is only available from another source

```
E: Package 'openssh-server' has no installation candidate
```

I also tried with

```
/etc/init.d/ssh restart
```

got response as,

```
bash: /etc/init.d/ssh: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Please, copy/paste the output of : `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

Answer (score 3):

This is because 11.10 [went End Of Life a year or so ago](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) - it would be much better to upgrade to a newer release like 14.04, which is available from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/download).

An alternative would be to download the packages you need from http://packages.ubuntu.com - e.g. openssh-server server can be found [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/openssh-server).
You will likely also need to download some the dependencies as well *(highlighted with the red dot - you may have some/most installed anyway)*.

A much better method than downloading the packages would be to use the method that can be found here:
[How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release)